# How to Remove Arrow-like Cursor from Turtle Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I create a polygon, e.g., using Turtle and save it to an eps file, but the arrow-like cursor remains in the image.  How can I get rid of any/all cursors?

I have tried hideturtle(), thinking perhaps "turtle" was generic for ANY cursor.

```
polygon = turtle.Turtle()
num_sides = 6
side_length = 70
angle = 360.0 / num_sides 
for i in range(num_sides):
    polygon.forward(side_length)
    polygon.right(angle)
ts = turtle.getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="hex_example.eps")
```

Comment: did you tried to move turtle far away from your image ?

Comment: Move it away and change the color of the line?  No, I have not.  Is there no way to just not show the arrowhead?

Comment: `hideturtle()` is for hiding arrowhead - but as you said postscript doesn't respect it.

Comment: It also shows in the pop-up window where the turtle creates the hexagon.

Answer (score 1):

This one is subtle, but here goes.  You can fix this problem by replacing:

```
ts = turtle.getscreen()
```

with either:

```
ts = polygon.getscreen()
```

or:

```
ts = turtle.Screen()
```

and putting back your:

```
polygon.hideturtle()
```

The problem is that `getscreen()` is a *turtle* method, so when you call it with the module name `turtle.getscreen()` it applies to the *default* turtle.  It not only gets you the screen, but also instantiates the default turtle.  The turtle you see in your PostScript image is not `polygon` but the unamed default turtle (your `polygon` *returns* to the home position, the *default* turtle *starts* at the home position).  By switching to either of the alternate invocations above to obtain the screen, you aren't instantiating the default turtle.  A complete solution:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

num_sides = 6
side_length = 70
angle = 360.0 / num_sides 

screen = Screen()

polygon = Turtle()

for _ in range(num_sides):
    polygon.forward(side_length)
    polygon.right(angle)

polygon.hideturtle()

screen.getcanvas().postscript(file="hex_example.eps")
```

This is the typical scenario for which I urge people to import turtle using:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
```

as it gives you *only* the *object-oriented* API for turtle, rather than other imports like `import turtle` or `from turtle import *` which  leave *both* the *object-oriented* API and the *functional* API active.  Having both active just confuses things.